# Linq Query returning null parameters when selecting whole table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm quite new to Linq but have been using it a lot recently and have been growing in confidence. I am accessing my db via a Context within an MVC project using EF.

All I want to do in this instance is fetch all data from one of my tables.

```
var msgs = context.Messages.ToList();
```

I feel like this is fine, however when I later use the list:

```
foreach(Message m in msgs)
{

     var info = context.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id == m.recipient.Id)
                                .Select(x => x.MobileNumber).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

The Message object has a mandatory `Recipient` which is a Contact object (another entity in my database).

I get a `NullArgumentException` on the line above because the Recipient parameter of the message objects are null in my list, despite them not being null in the database.

The strange thing is that the list is the right size, so it enters the foreach loop. The list is being correctly selected but all of the properties are null according to my debugger.

Confused by this I ran the line:

```
console.WriteLine(context.Messages.Select(x => x.Recipient.FirstName).FirstOrDefault());
```

and the first name of the Recipient of the first message was written to the console fine. So when I select individually I can retrieve the Recipient of the message and all of their information, but when trying to retrieve the entire table and store it in a list the recipient object is null.

Like I said, I am accessing this from outside of my MVC project which contains the context. I am utilising it from another project. This other project however contains references to both my MVC project which contains the db's Message model, and another project which contains a different class called Message. Could this ambiguity be the source of the problem or is there something else wrong with what I am doing?

**EDIT** I've created a bit of confusion about my issue apparently. The problem is that once I retrieve the list, the list is of the correct size, but the parameters of the message objects in the list are null. So for example if I write:

```
foreach (Message m in msgs)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("List Element Exists");
            if (m.Recipient != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Recipient.FirstName);
            }
        }
```

I get the output:

`List Element Exists
List Element Exists
List Element Exists
List Element Exists`

for each element in the list.

JK

Comment: Console.WriteLine(String) will not throw exception on null argument. Tell exact place where exception is thrown.

Comment: What *exactly* is `null` when you debug this?  I would expect that `m.Text` would be `null` for any records where that field is `null` in the database.

Comment: If m is null probably is a mapping issue. Also, is Text of type string and mapped directly to the table?

Comment: Is Text a required field in the database?

Comment: I apologise that I simplified the problem to try and show the isolated issue. Please see the edit. The null exception refers to Recipient object of my message. My message has a required Recipient, which is a Contact (another entity in my database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably the result of `where` condition is null in the linq query.

```
var info = context.Contacts.Where(x => x.Id == m.recipient.Id)
                                .Select(x => x.MobileNumber).FirstOrDefault()
```

Also the query itself has some problems, you may write the same query as:

```
var mobileNumber = string.Empty; //if it is not a string then initialize with proper value
var info = context.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == m.recipient.Id);
if(info != null)
    mobileNumber = info.MobileNumber;
```

Also there is another problem; if you execute this line:

```
var msgs = context.Messages.ToList();
```

it will fetch all `Messages` from DB; but you only need one phone number. So instead of fetching all records just execute the query I have provided and do not call foreach.

Edit

When `ToList()` is executed, db query is executed immediately; which means that `Recipient` property of `Message` object will not be loaded. Depending on whether you are using Lazy Loading or Eager Loading, you need another mechanism to fetch the `Recipient` property. Something like;

```
var msgs = context.Messages.Include(b => b.Recipients).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This still throws throws the exception. The exception is because for some reason the `Recipient` contact object is null in my list of Messages. The reason I retreive all of the messages is because I use the list in other ways within the Foreach loop. The line you see is the first line of a large process. I need all of the messages....

Comment: I've never come across the include function before...but thanks it has worked fine. so I guess with complex properties you have to specify to include them.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect that msg.Recipient contains something (i.e. on DB the data is compiled), it's a mapping issue. The most common issue is that Recipient property is not marked as virtual.

EDIT
Or, even worst, the class is marked as sealed but this usually does not happen

Comment: I was not aware of Lazy-loading vs. Eager-loading as I'm quite new to this area. I can only accept one answer but I voted up as I learnt something from both. Thanks. Would you say the advantage of using eager-loading to only load what you need for a given situation is preferable?